# Django Nginx Gunicorn is not taking the changse for new urls

Tags: server, nginx, django

I recently deployed my first project on digital Digital ocean.

I got it working and the site is live, but later when I updated some files I got stuck because the new urls I created are not being updated on the server.

I get this error if I put a url path on my temples

> Reverse for 'prospect-email' not found. 'prospect-email' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I only have this issue with the urls. Templates and static seem to be fine.

This are the files...

**config/url**

```
path('', include('gtm.apps.general.urls', namespace='general')),
```

**general/urls.py**

```
path('prospect-email/', views.prospect_email_view, name='prospect-email'),
```

**general/views.py**

```
def prospect_email_view(request):
```

**Thank you in advance for all the help you can provide me.**

Comment: @victor_rizo Did you solve the problem. Just happened to me moving from Django `runserver` to Gunicorn + Nginx config.

Answer (score 0):

I made one change to an apps's `urls.py` and had the same probem. If I remove the url's *template tag* from the base template, then the site is fine.

What I did to fix the issue was:

1. delete [pyc files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48487012/343215)
2. [Reload nginx](https://linuxize.com/post/nginx-commands-you-should-know/) `sudo systemctl reload nginx`
3. Following the [install instructions for gunicorn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-debian-9) I used systemctl to restart gunicorn.socket

I've been using Nginx/Gunicorn all of 20 hours. Not sure why it worked--just worked. Good luck.

Debian10/Nginx1.14/Gunicorn20.1/postgres11.9/Django3.1